# I cannot deploy the project. Problem with docker-compose and nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

There is a working script in yii2, I can't deploy it.
Docker builds the project, everything is fine, but if i substitute the nginx config from docker into nginx / sites-available / default, then an error appears:
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "app:9000" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:111
I read on the forums that i need to add the depends_on directive:
depend_on:
-app
but in this case, errors start to appear in:
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d

I substituted different versions - from "1" to "3.4", errors still appear. Here's the last one:
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.environment: 'XDEBUG_CONFIG'
Invalid top-level property "environment". Valid top-level sections for this Comp                                       ose file are: services, version, networks, volumes, and extensions starting with                                        "x-".

You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file versi                                       on. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your servi                                       ce definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place you                                       r service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compos                                       e/compose-file/

The project only works on php-7.0

Here is the original (from project) nginx config:

```
## FRONTEND ##
server {
    listen 80 default;

    root /app/frontend/web;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name yii2-starter-kit.dev;

    charset utf-8;

    # location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|pdf|ppt|txt|bmp|rtf|js)$ {
    #    access_log off;
    #    expires max;
    # }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    client_max_body_size 32m;

    # There is a VirtualBox bug related to sendfile that can lead to
    # corrupted files, if not turned-off
    # sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

        ## Cache
        # fastcgi_pass_header Cookie; # fill cookie valiables, $cookie_phpsessid for exmaple
        # fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie; # Use it with caution because it is cause SEO problems
        # fastcgi_cache_key "$request_method|$server_addr:$server_port$request_uri|$cookie_phpsessid"; # generating unique key
        # fastcgi_cache fastcgi_cache; # use fastcgi_cache keys_zone
        # fastcgi_cache_path /tmp/nginx/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=fastcgi_cache:16m max_size=256m inactive=1d;
        # fastcgi_temp_path  /tmp/nginx/temp 1 2; # temp files folder
        # fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500; # show cached page if error (even if it is outdated)
        # fastcgi_cache_valid 200 404 10s; # cache lifetime for 200 404;
        # or fastcgi_cache_valid any 10s; # use it if you want to cache any responses
    }
}

## BACKEND ##
server {
    listen 80;

    root /app/backend/web;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name backend.yii2-starter-kit.dev;

    charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 16m;

    # There is a VirtualBox bug related to sendfile that can lead to
    # corrupted files, if not turned-off on Vagrant based setup
    # sendfile off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|pdf|ppt|txt|bmp|rtf|js)$ {
    #     access_log off;
    #    expires max;
    # }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}

## STORAGE ##
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name storage.yii2-starter-kit.dev;

    root /app/storage/web;
    index index.html;
    # expires max;

    # There is a VirtualBox bug related to sendfile that can lead to
    # corrupted files, if not turned-off
    # sendfile off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

## PHP-FPM Servers ##
upstream php-fpm {
    server app:9000;
}

## MISC ##

### WWW Redirect ###
#server {
#    listen       80;
#    server_name  www.yii2-starter-kit.dev;
#    return       301 http://yii2-starter-kit.dev$request_uri;
#}
```

Original (from project) docker-compose.yml

```
data:
  image: busybox:latest
  volumes:
    - ./:/app
  entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null

app:
  build: docker/php
  working_dir: /app
  volumes_from:
    - data
  expose:
    - 9000
  links:
    - db
    - mailcatcher
  environment:
    XDEBUG_CONFIG: "idekey=PHPSTORM remote_enable=On remote_connect_back=On"

nginx:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./:/app
    - ./docker/nginx/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/vhost.conf
  links:
    - app

mailcatcher:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher:latest
    ports:
      - "1080:1080"

db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_DATABASE: yii2-starter-kit
    MYSQL_USER: ysk_dbu
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: ysk_pass
```

Help please make correct configs for nginx and docker-compose.

At yii2 newbie.
I would be very grateful for any help and advice.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A Compose file without a `version:` key at the top level is a [version 1 Compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/).  This is a *very* old version of the Compose YAML file format that doesn't support networks, volumes, or other modern Compose features.  You should select either version 2 or 3.  (Version 3 is a little more oriented towards Docker's Swarm orchestrator, so for some specific options in a single-host setup you may need to specify version 2.)  You need to specify a top-level `version:` key, and then the services you have need to go under a top-level `services:` key.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app: { ... }
  nginx: { ... }
  mailcatcher: { ... }
  db: { ... }
```

This will actually directly address your immediate issue.  As discussed in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), Compose (with a version 2 or 3 config file) will create a `default` network for you and register containers so that their service names (like `app`) are usable as host names.  You do not need `links:` or other configuration.

There are also a number of other unnecessary options in the Compose file you show.  You don't need to repeat an image's `WORKDIR` as a container's `working_dir:`; you don't need to `expose:` ports (as distinct from publishing `ports:` out to the host); it's not really great practice to overwrite the code that gets `COPY`ed into an image with `volumes:` from the host.

In modern Docker you also tend to not use data-volume containers.  Instead, newer versions of Compose have a [top-level `volumes:` key](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) that can declare named volumes.  You'd use this, for example, for your backing database storage.

The net result of all of this would be a Compose file like:

```yaml
# Specify a current Compose version.
version: '3.8'

# Declare that we'll need a named volume for the database storage.
volumes:
  mysql_data:

# The actual Compose-managed services.
services:
  app:
    build:
      # If the application is in ./app, then the build context
      # directory must be the current directory (to be able to
      #   COPY app ./
      # ).
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "idekey=PHPSTORM remote_enable=On remote_connect_back=On"

  nginx:
    # Build a separate image that will also
    #   FROM nginx
    #   COPY app /usr/share/nginx/html
    #   COPY docker/nginx/vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  mailcatcher:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher:latest
    ports:
      - "1080:1080"

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      # Use the named volume we declared above
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: yii2-starter-kit
      MYSQL_USER: ysk_dbu
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ysk_pass
```